# MySQL Database schema comparison between PROD and UAT server

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, mysql-workbench

I have to perform a MySQL DB schema comparison between PROD and UAT environment. Can anyone help me here on how to perform the same since I am doing this activity for the first time? I have found couple of articles online but those are for 2 tables in a specific DB or 2 tables in different DBs whereas in some article they say to buy a 3rd party tool. What I need here is **comparison of DBs schema on 2 different servers(PROD and UAT)** using SQL query or Linux shell script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of validations you would need to do across PROD and UAT environment? Because if you are doing data checks, mostly it would be a diff between the same table from both environments(UAT and PROD).

Comment: Hello Mayank,

Yes, I need to perform a schema comparison between Prod & UAT environment to identify any column difference between common tables along with any datatype or datatype length differences.

Comment: If it is just about schema comparisons, you can create 2 files one with the DDL's of all PROD tables and another with all UAT tables. Then you can simply do a unix file `diff` between the 2 files, it will give you differences(if any).
Note: There are tools available for such a purpose. You might want to use those for a bigger level comparison.

Comment: Thank you Mayank. I will try the steps that you have mentioned and will update the article if I find any errors. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of schema comparison tools around. 
[dbForge Schema Compare for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/schemacompare/download.html) comes with a 30-day trial period. You can use it in order to compare and synchronize schemas/databases on different hosts.

Some other options are [Toad Edge](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-edge/) or [navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql).

Alternatively, you can use `mysqldump` for both schemas and find their differences:

```
mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -u root -p db_prod>prod.sql
mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -u root -p db_uat>uat.sql
diff prod.sql uat.sql
```

but you'd have to manually synchronize the schemas.